# Bluetooth not transferring on Acer E5-532 running Ubuntu Mate

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, mate-desktop

Recently did fresh install on Laptop. Bluetooth adapter can pair with devices fine. Currently have it paired with my android mobile. Issue however arises when I try to transfer any files to device.Installed packages Bluez Bluetooth Bluetooth Transfer Indicator bluetooth to see if issue would resolve but nothing. Output from ***sudo service bluetooth status:***

bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-10-10 05:30:03 GYT; 11h ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1390 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1390 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: Not enough free handles to register 
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: Current Time Service could not be re
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: Not enough free handles to register 
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: Not enough free handles to register 
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Oct 10 05:30:03 Aspire-E5 bluetoothd[1390]: sap-server: Operation not permitted

Version info..
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 Mate
4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I can't seem to find any other errors in /var/log/syslog. This is my first time using bluetooth on linux. Any assistance would be appreciated